# plot lsmobj ref.grid: setting argument horiz=T supresses xlab argument

Tags: r, plot, lattice, axis-labels

In the `lsmeans` package, you can plot a `lsmobj (ref.grid)` object through the default `plot()` function.

```
# Uses supplied dataset 'fiber'
fiber.lm <- lm(strength ~ diameter + machine, data = fiber)

# adjusted means and comparisons, treating machine C as control
fiber.lsm <- lsmeans (fiber.lm, "machine")
plot(fiber.lsm)
```

To customize the x and y axis labels, using the standard `xlab` and `ylab` arguments.

```
plot(fiber.lsm, xlab="Estimated Strength", ylab="Machine Type")
```

However, putting the categorical variables on the x-axis, using `horiz=F`, seems to suppress the `xlab` argument (though not the `ylab` argument).

```
plot(fiber.lsm, horiz=F, ylab="Estimated Strength", xlab="Machine Type")
```

Any thoughts on how to plot with `horiz=F` while allowing the x axis label to be customized? This may be an issue with the `lsmeans` package, or the underlying `lattice` package. I'd be happy with the ability to suppress the x-axis label altogether and add it on later with `title`, but this doesn't seem to work on `lattice` plots.

Comment: I'll look at this and fix it in the next update if there's an error. BTW, you mean there's a problem when `horiz = FALSE` -- not `TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error and it will work right in version 2.13 - perhaps on CRAN mid-November or so.

```
> plot(fiber.lsm, horiz=F, ylab="Estimated Strength", xlab="Machine Type")
```

[image: vertical plot, properly labeled]

Thanks for reporting this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'd prefer to use their own function but using ggplot2:

```
tmp<-data.frame(summary(fiber.lsm))
ggplot(tmp, aes(x=machine, y=lsmean)) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower.CL, ymax=upper.CL), width=.1) +
geom_point()+
labs(x="Machine Type", y="Estimated Strength")
```

The default is the direction you want, I think, but if you want to flip the plot use + coord_flip()